# How does gradle handle multi modules with different support library v4 revisions?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have an Android project which depends on different modules and each modules depends on different revision of the android support-v4 library

1) My app also depends on the latest android support-v4 library (revision 21) so in this build.gralde I put a line like that:

```
dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
        }
```

2) Facebook SDK (v.3.15) module that also depends on the android support library v4, but revision 13 and its build.gradle file says:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
        compile files('../libs/bolts.jar')
    }
```

3) and one more module that, we can call Module3 in that case, also depends on the support-v4 but with a different revision than the other modules, like that:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
        compile files('../libs/bolts.jar')
    }
```

**Questions:**

1) How does gradle handle different support-v4 library revisions?

2) What does it do exactly?

3) What does it mean in terms of apk size?

Comment: "How does gradle handle different support-v4 library revisions?" -- depending on the `build.gradle` `compile` settings, it will either use one that matches everything, or it will fail the build. There can only be one copy of any given dependency in the app, as otherwise there will be collisions on class names.

Comment: Could you explain it better for this example, please? Does it mean gradle uses tha latest revision for this example?

Comment: My gut instinct would be that it will fail the build, as there is no version of that library that is simultaneously three different versions. But, I have not played with this scenario much. If you have this already set up, run a Gradle dependencies report to see exactly what it will use: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html (see "Listing project dependencies")

Comment: I don't have my laptop with and I can try it to see if it fails or not. Anyway my intention is to force every module to use the latest revision. But I am afraid to break something in those module. What would you suggest?

Comment: "Anyway my intention is to force every module to use the latest revision" -- there are ways to do this, using `exclude` options to say that you want a dependency (e.g., Facebook SDK) but to exclude certain transitive dependencies, that you will be satisfying elsewhere. "What would you suggest?" -- lots and lots of testing. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please show how to do it (force all module to use the latest versions, as used in the app) ? Or provide a link/tutorial for how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

In this case Gradle will fail the build (tested on my skin and I did not find other solutions)
"Unfortunately" you have to use the same version of support on any module.

From [docs.gradle.com](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):

Gradle offers the following conflict resolution strategies:

- **Newest**: The newest version of the dependency is used. This is Gradle's default strategy, and is often an appropriate choice as long as versions are backwards-compatible.
- **Fail**: A version conflict results in a build failure. This strategy requires all version conflicts to be resolved explicitly in the build script. See ResolutionStrategy for details on how to explicitly choose a particular version.

While the strategies introduced above are usually enough to solve most conflicts, Gradle provides more fine-grained mechanisms to resolve version conflicts:

- Configuring a first level dependency as **forced**. This approach is useful if the dependency in conflict is already a first level dependency. See examples in **[DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html)**.
- Configuring any dependency (transitive or not) as **forced**. This approach is useful if the dependency in conflict is a transitive dependency. It also can be used to force versions of first level dependencies. See examples in **[ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)**
- Dependency resolve rules are an incubating feature introduced in Gradle 1.4 which give you fine-grained control over the version selected for a particular dependency.